# Convergence of series $\{r^n\}$ for $r=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is stated at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Sequences.aspx (a well-known math website) under Theorem 3 that the sequence $(1^n)^\infty_{n=0}$ converges for $r=1$.

However if we were to analyse the series $(1^n)$, it is basically 
$$\ (1^n)^\infty_{n=0}=1+1+1+1+....=\infty$$
which implies divergence.

So what mistake I am making over here?

Comment: It is **not** the series, but the sequence $(1^n)=(1,1,1,1,1,\cdots,)$. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}1^n=1$.

Comment: sequence $\ne$ series.

Comment: Wait does convergence means the sum having a finite value or does all terms having finite value?

Comment: @FaiqRaees what you mentioned is convergence for series

Comment: A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $r$ if $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n\ge N,\lvert a_n-r\rvert<\varepsilon.$$ A series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ converges to $r$ if the sequence $\left\{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the notion of a **sequence** with that of a **series**. As technical terms, they have quite different meanings.

If $a_n$ is a number for each $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, then the **sequence with terms $a_n$** is the ordered list of numbers $$a_0$$ $$a_1$$ $$a_2$$ $$a_3$$ $$\cdots$$
On the other hand, the **series with terms $a_n$** is the ordered list of numbers
$$a_0$$
$$a_0+a_1$$
$$a_0+a_1+a_2$$
$$a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3$$
$$\cdots$$
So the series is a *new sequence* which is derived from the original sequence by declaring that the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ term of the new sequence is
$$s_n=a_0+a_1+\cdots + a_n\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k$$
This new sequence may or may not converge; if it converges, say $s_n\to s$, then we write
$$s = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} s_n =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$$
Note that in each of the two displayed lines above, the symbol on the right end is *defined* by what precedes it. Furthermore, $s_n=\sum\limits^n$ is a **finite sum** for each $n$, but $s=\sum\limits^{\infty}$ is **not a sum** -- rather it is a **limit of a sequence of finite sums**. The difference is that you can add up a finite number of terms literally, but you cannot add up an infinite number of terms. You can only take the limit of the resulting sequence of sums. It is literally impossible to perform an infinite number of additions.

One often speaks of an infinite series as an infinite sum, but that's not really true.

So, in your case, the original sequence is $1,1,1,\cdots$, which converges to $1$, but the corresponding series is $1, 2, 3, \cdots$, which does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $(1^n)=(1,1,1\cdots)$ converges, the series $\sum1=1+1+1\cdots$ diverges.

Comment: So if a sequence had a term having infinite value, it will be divergent?

Comment: Do you know the definition of converges of a sequence?

Comment: @FaiqRaees The convergence/divergence of *sequence* is one thing, but the convergence/divergence of *series* is different.

Comment: I have only studied the concepts of convergence and divergence with series. It's the first time I have seen that even sequences have convergence

Comment: @FaiqRaees Then you need to read up on [convergence of sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Limits_and_convergence) and not confuse it with converges of series. Though it is surprising that you've studied convergence of series before convergence of sequences as that latter is normally studied before.

Comment: A sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,…)$ is said to converge if there is some limit $L$ such that for every positive number $\epsilon$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|x_n−L|<\epsilon$, and we write $x_n \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @FaiqRaees This is really surprising. Convergence of a series is usually defined as the convergence of the sequence of partial sums. What is the definition you have learned?

Answer (score 0):

$$(1^n)_{n=0}^\infty = (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots)\neq 1+1+1+\cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1^n$$

The sequence $a_n=1^n$ converges to $1$. because there exists, for every $\epsilon > 0$, such a $N>0$ that if $n>N$ then $|a_n - 1| < \epsilon$. We write that as $$\lim_{n=1}^\infty 1^n = 1$$

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1^n$ does **not** converge.